# How to access a dynamic control in mshtml created through javascript

Tags: mshtml, microsoft.mshtml

How to access a dynamic control in mshtml created through javascript.

I have a Yes/No radio button. On selecting Yes, a textbox is dynamically created and added next to this radio button. I am able to access the radio button using HTMLDocument.getElementsByName or HTMLDocument.getElementById or HTMLDocument.all.item.

I want to access the newly created textbox. The code for creating the dynamic textbox is in javascript and I dont have any control on it.

```
HTMLDocument.getElementById("testId")
```

returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a new thread. If we try to use the main thread HTMLDocument does not show dynamically created controls.